# London equation and Maxwell equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, superconductivity

I am reading [Tinkham's *Introduction to Superconductivity* (2nd ed)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486435032) (Amazon link).

On pages 4-5, they state that:"

> The second London equation 1.4, when combined with the Maxwell equation ${\rm curl}\ h = \frac{4\pi J}{c}$ leads to:
>   $$\nabla^2 h = \frac{h}{\lambda^2}$$

where equation (1.4) is:

$$\ h=-c\ {\rm curl} \ (\Lambda J_s )\tag{1.4}$$
$$\Lambda = \frac{4\pi \lambda^2}{c^2}$$

If I take a curl on (1.4) and equate it with Maxwell equation I get: 
$${\rm curl} \ h = - c \ {\rm curl}\ {\rm curl}\ (\Lambda J_s) = -c(\nabla(\nabla \cdot) -\nabla^2)\Lambda J_s=(\dagger);$$

I don't see how do they get $\nabla^2h =h/\lambda^2$. I do get: $\nabla^2 J =J/\lambda^2$, if the first term in $(dagger)$ is zero, and $J_s=J$.

So is this a misprint in the book, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**:

1. Given the Maxwell equation:
   $$
   \nabla\times\mathbf h=\frac{4\pi}{c}\mathbf J
   $$
   Take the curl of both sides, what do you get? How can (1.4) be used here?
2. Vector calculus tells you
   $$
   \nabla\times\nabla\times\mathbf a=\nabla\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf a\right)-\nabla^2\mathbf a
   $$
   What assumptions must you make to get the London equation?

Comment: I did just that and got what I wrote, $\nabla^2 J = J /\lambda^2$

Comment: You're trying to prove the relationship with $\mathbf h$, so I'm not sure why you insist that $\mathbf J$ is there.

Comment: Since, if $curl h = 4\pi /c J$ and , $h=-c \ curl (\Lambda J)$, then $curl \ h = -c \ curl \ curl \ (\Lambda J) = c\Lambda \nabla^2 J$, equating I get a relation between Laplacian of J and J, I don't see how do they get the relation for laplacian of h and h.

Comment: Then you have not yet followed my directions/suggestions.

Comment: Think about it: you are trying to find a relationship for $h$, right? So why are you *replacing* it when you should be *gathering* it?